# How can I create a SQL query from an HTML form in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I have a form that accepts 2 text fields and 1 radio button with 3 options. I'd like to turn those 3 inputs into a SQL (MS SQL Server) `INSERT INTO` statement to create a new user in a database. It works if I user literals for the value parameter of my request.input but if I change the value parameter to something else like `req.body.first_name` it still creates a new row in my database but all 3 fields are `NULL`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my simple form:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Users</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="E:\Projects\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><center>Add a new user</center></h1><br>

    <center>
      <form action = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/user" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type ="text" name ="first_name" placeholder="Enter First Name"><br>
         <br>
         <input type ="text" name = "last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name"><br>
         <br>
         <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"> Male
         <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"> Female
         <input type="radio" name="gender" id="other" value="other"> Other<br>
         <br>
         <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
      </form><br>
    </center>

    <h1><center>List all users</center></h1><br>

    <center>
      <form action = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/user" method = "GET">
         <input type = "submit" value = "Go get'em!">
      </form>
    </center>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <script src="sql.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my Node.js file (yes I have 2 POST APIs. One is commented out while I try and figure out what's going on. So my `POST URL` should look like this `localhost:8080/api/user?first_name=Timmy&last_name=Johnson&gender=Male:`

```
//Initiallising node modules
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var sql = require("mssql");
var form = require('multer');

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/html' }));

//CORS Middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    //Enabling CORS
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});

//Setting up server
 var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port", port);
 });

// Configure database connection
var dbConfig = {
    user: 'user',
    domain: 'domain',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'server',
    database: 'database'
};


//Function to connect to database and execute query
var  executeQuery = function(res, query){
     sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
         if (err) {
                     console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err);
                     res.send(err);
                  }
                  else {
                         // create Request object
                         var request = new sql.Request();
                         // query to the database
                         request.query(query, function (err, rs) {
                           if (err) {
                                      console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
                                      res.send(err);
                                     }
                                     else {
                                       res.send(rs);
                                       sql.close();
                                            }
                               });
                       }
      });
};

//GET API
app.get("/api/user", function(req , res){
                var query = "select * from [Names]";
                executeQuery (res, query);
});

// //POST API
app.post('/api/user', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.input('first_name',sql.VarChar,req.body.first_name);
        request.input('last_name',sql.VarChar,req.body.last_name);
        request.input('gender',sql.VarChar,req.body.gender);

        request.query("INSERT INTO Names (First_Name, Last_Name, Gender) VALUES (@first_name, @last_name, @gender)", function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);
            sql.close();
        });
    });
});

// //POST API
//  app.post("/api/user", function(req , res){
//                 //var query = "INSERT INTO Names (First_Name, Last_Name, Gender) VALUES ('Test', 'User', 'Female')";
//                 var query = "INSERT INTO Names (First_Name,Last_Name,Gender) VALUES ()";
//                 executeQuery (res, query);
// });

//PUT API
 app.put("/api/user/:id", function(req , res){
                var query = "UPDATE [Names] SET First_Name= " + req.body.first_name  +  " , Last_Name=  " + req.body.last_name + " , Gender=  " + req.body.gender + "  WHERE Id= " + req.params.id;
                executeQuery (res, query);
});

// DELETE API
 app.delete("/api/user/:id", function(req , res){
                var query = "DELETE FROM [Names] WHERE Id=" + req.params.id;
                executeQuery (res, query);
});
```

Comment: Your CORS opens up lots of security holes.

Comment: I got most of the code from this tutorial: https://vmokshagroup.com/blog/building-restful-apis-using-node-js-express-js-and-ms-sql-server/

Got any recommendations to close it up a bit?

Comment: You probably shouldn't use CORS at all.

Comment: I removed all that CORS code and it all still works (well, minus my posted issue) so if I don't need it I won't use it. :)

Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Simplifying my POST API to just this shows me that it doesn't know what req.body.<value> is at all.  
`//POST API
 app.post("/api/user", urlencodedParser, function(req , res){
   response = {
      first_name:req.body.first_name,
      last_name:req.body.last_name,
      gender:req.body.gender
   };
                console.log(response);
                // console.log(req.body.last_name);
                // console.log(req.body.gender);
});`

Console response is:  
`App now running on port 8080
{ first_name: undefined,
  last_name: undefined,
  gender: undefined }`

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some head-to-keyboard banging here is the answer to my own question.

I had 2 problems. The **first** problem is with my "user input" form. I had some confusion regarding the meaning of `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` and my form was posting with that and was encoding my form data which was completely unnecessary. So I removed that from my form.

The **second** problem was with building my SQL query. I was over complicating things. Also, I had some extra stuff in there that simply wasn't needed that @SLaks pointed out. So, here is the final Node.js code with the working POST code:

```
//Initiallising node modules
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var sql = require("mssql");

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Setting up server
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("App now running on port", port);
});

// Configure database connection
var dbConfig = {
  user: 'user',
  domain: 'domain',
  password: 'password',
  server: 'dbserver',
  database: 'database'
};

//Function to connect to database and execute query
var  executeQuery = function(res, query){
  sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err);
      res.send(err);
    }
    else {
      // create Request object
      var request = new sql.Request();
      // query to the database
      request.query(query, function (err, rs) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
          res.send(err);
        }
        else {
          res.send(rs);
          sql.close();
        }
      });
    }
  });
};

//GET API
app.get("/api/user", function(req , res){
  var query = "select * from [Names]";
  executeQuery (res, query);
});

//POST API
app.post("/api/user", function(req , res){
  var formData = {
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    gender: req.body.gender
  };

  var query = `INSERT INTO Names (First_Name,Last_Name,Gender) VALUES ('${formData.first_name}', '${formData.last_name}', '${formData.gender}')`;
  console.log(query);
  executeQuery (res, query);
});
```

Comment: Just a heads up: this code is highly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks because you are just taking whatever the client passes you in the request body and plopping it into a raw SQL query. Be sure to read the docs for the library you are using to connect to the database, and if it does not provide an API for parameterized query building, consider using an ORM like Knex.js.